# Quick relabeling of factors in data table

Tags: r, data.table

I relabel a lot of factors using data.table in R. This often involves a lot of copying and pasting. I'm wondering if I can use the drop down list type thing in R to speed this up. So for example when you type `df$` it gives a drop down from which to select. Here is an example:

```
# Create example df
Batch <- rep(LETTERS[seq(from=1, to =10)], each=1)
Date <- rep(seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), length.out = 5, by="1 day"), each=2)
df <- data.table(Batch, Date)

# Show factor combinations
with(df, table(Date, Batch))

# Add new column based on factor labels. 
df[Date=="2001-01-01", NewBatch:="hello"]
df[Date=="2001-01-02", NewBatch:="world"]
#etc
```

As you can see this can get quite lengthy if I have ten or so factors. I was thinking something like:

```
df$Date <- factor(df$Date)
labs <- data.frame(unique(df$Date))
ndf <- matrix(, nrow=1, ncol=length(labs$unique.df.Date.))
ndf <- data.frame(ndf)
colnames(ndf) <- c(labs[1],labs[2],labs[3],labs[4],labs[5])
```

Then I type `ndf$` and I get a drop down of all the factors. However, this is quite messy. Any ideas to make it neat?

Thanks

Update trying suggestions:

```
lookup <- data.table(Date = as.Date(unique(df[["Date"]])) , Newbatch = c("h","e","l","l","o"))


df[lookup, Newbatch:=i.Newbatch, on="Date"]
```

The above works nicely.

Comment: Create a look-up data.table and do a join instead of your method.

Comment: Hi Roland. Doesn't that involve the same amount of copying and pasting or am I being daft? I will edit my question with what I think you mean, please correct if not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand your question, but I would do this:

```
lookup <- data.table(Date = as.Date(c("2001-01-01", "2001-01-02")), 
                     #you could extract the preceding values using unique(df[["Date"]])
                     NewBatch = c("hello", "world"))
df[lookup, NewBatch := i.NewBatch, on = "Date"]
#    Batch       Date NewBatch
# 1:     A 2001-01-01    hello
# 2:     B 2001-01-01    hello
# 3:     C 2001-01-02    world
# 4:     D 2001-01-02    world
# 5:     E 2001-01-03       NA
# 6:     F 2001-01-03       NA
# 7:     G 2001-01-04       NA
# 8:     H 2001-01-04       NA
# 9:     I 2001-01-05       NA
#10:     J 2001-01-05       NA
```

Comment: Ah yes I see. But then I still have to literally type / copy and past the dates in the lookup. Sorry for the confusion. I was trying to get to a point where I don't have to copy the date. I will edit my question to try and make it clearer.

Comment: See the comment inside the code. You don't need to type the dates. (If you have many dates, this gets dangerous. With the look-up table you can check easily if dates and `newBatch` values align correctly.)

Comment: Ah ok, I see. I seem to get an unused argument error for some reason: Error in `[.data.table`(df, lookup, `:=`(Newbatch, Newbatch), on = "Date") : 
  unused argument (on = "Date")

Comment: I would use `NewBatch := i.NewBatch` in `j` arg just for clarity

Comment: @Pete900 upgrade data.table to 1.9.6 where `on` arg was introduced

Comment: Look at `lookup` and then fix your parentheses. `NewBatch` must be a column in the `lookup` data.table.

Comment: @jangorecki, what does the "i." do?

Comment: @Pete900 the `i.` prefix can be used in `j` argument to point that variable has to be taken from dataset provided in `i` argument. You have all the arguments described in `?data.table` manual.